# Quick sort implemented in Rust

Tags: beginner, rust, quick-sort

First attempt at writing Rust code.  What do you think of the formatting?  I think the type conversions are pretty messy.  How can I make it more idiomatic?

```
fn quicksort(array: &mut[isize], first: usize, last: usize) {
    if first < last {
        let midpoint = partition(array, first, last);
        quicksort(array, first, midpoint - 1);
        quicksort(array, midpoint + 1, last);
    }
}


fn partition(array: &mut[isize], first: usize, last: usize) -> usize {
    let pivot = array[last];

    let i: isize = first as isize;
    let mut i: isize = i - 1;

    let mut j = first;
    while j < last - 1 {
        if array[j] < pivot {
            i = i + 1;
            let k: usize = i as usize;
            swap(array, k, j);
        }
        j = j + 1;
    }

    let k: isize = i + 1;
    let k: usize = k as usize;
    if array[last] < array[k] {
        swap(array, k, last);
    }
    return k;
}


fn swap(array: &mut[isize], a: usize, b: usize) {
    let temp = array[a];
    array[a] = array[b];
    array[b] = temp;
}


fn main() {
    let mut array = [3, 5, 1, 4, 2];
    quicksort(&mut array, 0, 4);

    println!("{:?}", array);
}
```

Comment: C.A.R Hoares' original paper [*Quicksort*](https://watermark.silverchair.com/050010.pdf)

Comment: This link will provide a token by clicking on the PDF link, https://academic.oup.com/comjnl/article/5/1/10/395338

Answer (score 3):

1. **Your implementation is incorrect**. It fails for all sorts of inputs, but the simplest is

   ```
   let mut array = [0, 0];
   quicksort(&mut array, 0, 1);
   ```
2. Figuring out how to even call `quicksort` is overly complicated. Why do I have to pass in these numbers; can't the code figure that out?
3. Run [rustfmt](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustfmt). It will automatically tell you things like:

   - `&mut[T]` should be written as `&mut [T]`.
4. Run [clippy](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rust-clippy).  It will automatically tell you things like:

   - Not to use `return` at the end of a function.
   - That you can use `a += b` instead of `a = a + b`
   - That you've re-implemented [`slice::swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.swap)

---

Since the code doesn't work, I don't know that the transforms I made preserve the existing behavior. The rest is *caveat emptor*.

1. You have redundant type declarations. You don't need to say `let x: T = y as T`, just `let x = y as T`.
2. You also don't often need to specify the type at all, type inference can handle it.
3. Presumably you converted to an `isize` because you were subtracting one from zero. Instead, increase the values by one to keep it in the range of a `usize`. To transform, add one to the initial value of `i` and subtract one from the usages of `i`, then remove the casts and simplify the math.

```
fn partition(array: &mut [isize], first: usize, last: usize) -> usize {
    let pivot = array[last];

    let mut i = first;
    let mut j = first;

    while j < last - 1 {
        if array[j] < pivot {
            array.swap(i, j);
            i += 1;
        }
        j += 1;
    }

    if array[last] < array[i] {
        array.swap(i, last);
    }

    i
}
```